# Assign character column based on changing minimum and maximum values

Tags: r

I have some tide data that I would like to assign a character variable depending on the depth.

I would like to classify `df1$t_depth` into either `Flood`, `Ebb` or `Slack`, in a column called `df1$p_wave`.

Here is an example of my data.

```
    datetime          t_depth
1  23/03/2018 22:59 0.7200000
2  23/03/2018 23:59 0.8652785
3  24/03/2018 00:59 1.0105569
4  24/03/2018 01:59 1.1558354
5  24/03/2018 02:59 1.3011138
6  24/03/2018 03:59 1.4463923
7  24/03/2018 05:52 1.7200000
8  24/03/2018 06:52 1.5875325
9  24/03/2018 07:52 1.4550649
10 24/03/2018 08:52 1.3225974
11 24/03/2018 09:52 1.1901299
12 24/03/2018 10:52 1.0576623
13 24/03/2018 12:17 0.8700000
14 24/03/2018 13:17 0.9723256
15 24/03/2018 14:17 1.0746512
16 24/03/2018 15:17 1.1769767
17 24/03/2018 16:17 1.2793023
18 24/03/2018 17:17 1.3816279
19 24/03/2018 18:44 1.5300000
20 24/03/2018 19:44 1.4452542
21 24/03/2018 20:44 1.3605085
22 24/03/2018 21:44 1.2757627
23 24/03/2018 22:44 1.1910169
24 25/03/2018 00:38 1.0300000
```

For `df1$p_wave`, I would like to categorise the highest tides as `Flood`, and the lowest as `Ebb` with `Slack` for every tide in between. However, the tidal periods are not all the same length, and the highest and lowest value in the whole period also change. I'm not sure of the best way to go about classifying these values with these changing conditions.

I thought that I  could do this using `df1$datetime`, as the minutes change with each tidal period, so low numbers at the beginning of a new tidal period would be the `Ebb` and high numbers `Flood`, but I'm not sure of a way to code this effectively.

I would like to be able to reproduce this for a dataset that covers multiple days.

```
           datetime   t_depth  p_wave
1  23/03/2018 22:59 0.7200000  Ebb
2  23/03/2018 23:59 0.8652785  Slack
3  24/03/2018 00:59 1.0105569  Slack
4  24/03/2018 01:59 1.1558354  Slack
5  24/03/2018 02:59 1.3011138  Slack
6  24/03/2018 03:59 1.4463923  Slack
7  24/03/2018 05:52 1.7200000  Flood
8  24/03/2018 06:52 1.5875325  Slack
9  24/03/2018 07:52 1.4550649  Slack
10 24/03/2018 08:52 1.3225974  Slack
11 24/03/2018 09:52 1.1901299  Slack
12 24/03/2018 10:52 1.0576623  Slack
13 24/03/2018 12:17 0.8700000  Ebb
14 24/03/2018 13:17 0.9723256  Slack
15 24/03/2018 14:17 1.0746512  Slack
16 24/03/2018 15:17 1.1769767  Slack
17 24/03/2018 16:17 1.2793023  Slack
18 24/03/2018 17:17 1.3816279  Slack
19 24/03/2018 18:44 1.5300000  Flood
20 24/03/2018 19:44 1.4452542  Slack
21 24/03/2018 20:44 1.3605085  Slack
22 24/03/2018 21:44 1.2757627  Slack
23 24/03/2018 22:44 1.1910169  Slack
24 25/03/2018 00:38 1.0300000  Ebb
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Data:

```
structure(list(datetime = structure(1:24, .Label = c("23/03/2018 22:59", 
"23/03/2018 23:59", "24/03/2018 00:59", "24/03/2018 01:59", "24/03/2018 02:59", 
"24/03/2018 03:59", "24/03/2018 05:52", "24/03/2018 06:52", "24/03/2018 07:52", 
"24/03/2018 08:52", "24/03/2018 09:52", "24/03/2018 10:52", "24/03/2018 12:17", 
"24/03/2018 13:17", "24/03/2018 14:17", "24/03/2018 15:17", "24/03/2018 16:17", 
"24/03/2018 17:17", "24/03/2018 18:44", "24/03/2018 19:44", "24/03/2018 20:44", 
"24/03/2018 21:44", "24/03/2018 22:44", "25/03/2018 00:38"), class = "factor"), 
    t_depth = c(0.72, 0.86527845, 1.010556901, 1.155835351, 1.301113801, 
    1.446392252, 1.72, 1.587532468, 1.455064935, 1.322597403, 
    1.19012987, 1.057662338, 0.87, 0.972325581, 1.074651163, 
    1.176976744, 1.279302326, 1.381627907, 1.53, 1.445254237, 
    1.360508475, 1.275762712, 1.191016949, 1.03)), row.names = c(NA, 
-24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Is there a defined threshold of `t_depth` that would result in Ebb and Flood?

Comment: Looks more like a matter of logic rather than computing. I can see a depth value of 1.53 as Flood, but earlier there's a value of 1.58 classified as Slack.

Comment: @denisafonin Sadly not, it just alternates between Ebb and Flood through the cycle, which changes when the minutes in `datetime` do. Sometimes there can be high ebbs and low floods which is what I'm struggling with!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From calculus we know that the first derivative changes its sign on local minima and maxima. This is also true in the discrete case. So we can just compute the derivative and check if its sign changes.

The simplest method to find the changes is to differentiate the sign vector again. It will be -2 for Flood and +2 for Ebb.

```
diff(sign(diff(df1$t_depth)))
#> [1]  0  0  0  0  0 -2  0  0  0  0  0  2  0  0  0  0  0 -2  0  0  0  0
```

Note that you cannot identify the state of the first and last row with this method. This is however clear, you never can know the status of the first and last row because you don't know if the water was rising or not before.

```
df1$p_wave <- c(NA, diff(sign(diff(df1$t_depth))), NA)
df1$p_wave <- cut(df1$p_wave, breaks = c(-3, -1, 1, 3), labels = c("Flood", "Slack", "Ebb"))

      df1
               datetime   t_depth p_wave
    1  23/03/2018 22:59 0.7200000   <NA>
    2  23/03/2018 23:59 0.8652785  Slack
    3  24/03/2018 00:59 1.0105569  Slack
    4  24/03/2018 01:59 1.1558354  Slack
    5  24/03/2018 02:59 1.3011138  Slack
    6  24/03/2018 03:59 1.4463923  Slack
    7  24/03/2018 05:52 1.7200000  Flood
    8  24/03/2018 06:52 1.5875325  Slack
    9  24/03/2018 07:52 1.4550649  Slack
    10 24/03/2018 08:52 1.3225974  Slack
    11 24/03/2018 09:52 1.1901299  Slack
    12 24/03/2018 10:52 1.0576623  Slack
    13 24/03/2018 12:17 0.8700000    Ebb
    14 24/03/2018 13:17 0.9723256  Slack
    15 24/03/2018 14:17 1.0746512  Slack
    16 24/03/2018 15:17 1.1769767  Slack
    17 24/03/2018 16:17 1.2793023  Slack
    18 24/03/2018 17:17 1.3816279  Slack
    19 24/03/2018 18:44 1.5300000  Flood
    20 24/03/2018 19:44 1.4452542  Slack
    21 24/03/2018 20:44 1.3605085  Slack
    22 24/03/2018 21:44 1.2757627  Slack
    23 24/03/2018 22:44 1.1910169  Slack
    24 25/03/2018 00:38 1.0300000   <NA>
```

Edit: You can add Falling and Rising status like this:

```
df1$p_wave <- c(NA, diff(sign(diff(df1$t_depth))), NA)
df1$p_wave[!is.na(df1$p_wave) & df1$p_wave == 0] <- sign(diff(df1$t_depth))[!is.na(df1$p_wave) & df1$p_wave == 0]
df1$p_wave <- cut(df1$p_wave,
                  breaks = c(-2.5, -1.5, 0, 1.5, 2.5),
                  labels = c("Flood", "Falling", "Rising", "Ebb"))
```

Comment: This is perfect and very easy! Thank you!

Comment: @AEF I was just wondering whether it would be possible to change Slack into either 'Rising', so values between Ebb-Flood, and 'Falling', values from Flood-Ebb. Do you know if there is a way I could edit this?

Comment: Sure, just remove the outermost `diff`. This will give you a vector indicating if it was rising or falling.

Comment: @AEF Thanks, that's great! Is there a way that I can do this so it retains the minimum and maximum ebb and flood which are -2 and 2, instead of these being changed to rising and falling, so that I could have Ebb, Rising, Flood and Falling values instead of just rising and falling?

Comment: I added it to my answer.